# Is switching workplaces supported for dual monitor?

Tags: multiple-monitors

I use dual monitor and I would like to switch workplaces in both monitors. Currently, when I move from one workplace to another, only the primary monitor changes.
How can I setup Ubuntu to switch workplaces in both monitors?

I'm using Ubuntu 21.10.

Answer (score 0):

Default Gnome Shell does not do that: the main monitor is where you switch workspaces, the second monitor is an extension of the first workspace where you can place some reference info etc.

There is a Gnome Shell extension that adds panels and overviews to any of the monitors. It is around for a long time, regularly updated and available in the standard Ubuntu software repositories for systemwide install:

```
sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-multi-monitors
```